# Xcode not reading php

Tags: php, xcode

Hi i was wondering if you have a webview displaying a url that has php in it, if you have to do a configuring for it to read the php because it doesnt read it it just displays the php code. Below is what it sends back to me when i try to display the web view.

```
<?php

$firstName = $_POST["firstName"]; 
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$dormName = $_POST["dormRoom"];
$roomNumber = $_POST["roomNumber"];
$pizzaType = $_POST["PizzaType"];

$fp = fopen($firstName . "_" . $lastName . ".txt", "a"); // the 'a' will append to the end of the file.

fwrite($fp, "First Name: $firstName");
fwrite($fp, "Last Name: $lastName");
fwrite($fp, "Dorm Name: $dormName");
fwrite($fp, "Room Number: $roomNumber");
fwrite($fp, "Pizza Type: $pizzaType");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: The PHP needs to be somehow interpreted. Where is it supposed to "run"?

Comment: As in, you are putting a .php file into your app bundle and expect it to be executed by opening it in a webview? And where does your PHP executable and a webserver come into this?

Comment: no im not putting any php into the xcode all of it is done on the server

Comment: Then your server is misconfigured, maybe this helps (assuming you're LAMPing): http://askubuntu.com/questions/59272/php-not-working-in-apache2-after-system-upgrade

Comment: @m90 the server works because when i load it in a browser it works fine

Comment: And you're seeing stuff like `<? echo 'Howdy there cowboys'; $now = time(); ?>` in the webview?

Comment: no because its not an echo function its writing to a file based on what my html page that has a form submits

Comment: To be honest I don't quite get what you are writing, could you edit your question and clarify what you are doing and what you are seeing in the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is interpreted by the PHP server. A UIWebView is basically a browser, meaning it is client-side. A UIWebView can only render HTML and execute client-side code like javascript.

Since PHP is executed server-side, you need to host your php code on a remote php server, then direct an http request to that server to execute the code and return the results to either the browser or a http request direct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no PHP server running on the iOS device. You will not be able to run PHP code inside an app. You'll have to program it in Objective-C, the language in which iOS apps are programmed.